# Irreducible Hausdorff Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, geometric-topology, zariski-topology

I was studying Zariski Topology, and we know that a Zariski topological space is not Hausdorff, now I want to know what are the irreducible Hausdorff topological spaeces?

Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: An irreducible Hausdorff space contains at most one point, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180083/irreducible-topological-spaces-and-irreducible-hausdorff-space).

Comment: Edited. Thank you.

Comment: Let $X$ be Hausdorff and $x\neq y\in X$. By assumption there exists $U,V$ neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ respectively such that $U\cap V=\emptyset$. But this implies that $X$ is not irreducible. Hence, $X$ is irreducible iff $X=\{x\}$.

Comment: So we for the topological spaces with finite elements it must have one element. What about the topological space with infinite elements?

Comment: Where did I said that $X$ is finite ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde By this the Irreducible Hausdorff Topological Spaces must have one element?

Comment: ... at most one. It could also be empty.

Comment: Thank you guys, I got the answer.

Comment: @Roland In topology almost every book doesn't add the non-empty condition. Things are not how they should be, but the way they are.

Comment: @Roland I know you don't know, that is why you are saying "in general" based on what you think it is, or what you think it should be. Now go and start opening books and links.

Comment: @Roland I think my background in algebraic geometry is enough to know what you are saying too. But, on the other hand, I have also opened enough books in topology to know that what I am saying is the case. Whether it shouldn't be is a different story. Definitions are made up things. Like everything human, it is often influenced by tradition, and culture.

Comment: you can find your answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180083/irreducible-topological-spaces-and-irreducible-hausdorff-space

Comment: @Roland is right in my opinion.

Comment: @Roland Even our colleagues at nLab [have left out the non-empty condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/irreducible+topological+space). Not just topologists and geometers. Your "in general" is more like wishful thinking than reality.

Comment: @B.K-Theory In my opinion too the definition looks better including the non-empty condition. That wish, though, doesn't make it a reality. So, if this problem appears in an assignment, you better consult your instructor/course book to see what they assumed as the definition.

Comment: @elmer I finally agree with you : what is important is to be coherent with the definition you have in hand. Shall we delete this fruitless conversation ?

Comment: @Roland I don't think so. It is an important remainder that mathematical exposition is a cultural phenomenon, and as such the reason behind some things is only tradition.

Comment: No, I have learned much from this topic.

Comment: @elmer I can't believe you. If you want example, look at the definition in Hartshorne, or look at the definition here : https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/004U. Maybe I was wrong that this is the usual convention, but it is certainly not made up. You quote nLab, but look at here : https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+space, they claim that the empty set should not be considered as connected... And I disagree with you, a definition/convention is meant to evolve if it is better for modern mathematics, an author does not have to stick with whatever historical decisions...

Comment: @Roland I never said it is made up. I also never said that a definition doesn't evolve, so you cannot disagree with me on that either. Actually, from me emphasizing that a definition is a cultural phenomenon it should be clear that I claim precisely that it evolves. The only thing that I said is that, so far as today's state of afairs your "in general" claim that irreducible spaces are assumed non-empty, it is not true. Maybe 200 years from now, 50, or 5, that could change.

Comment: @elmer No this clearly not what you meant with "Things are not how they should be, but the way they are", or " based on what you think it is, or what you think it should be." By the way, irreducible implies non empty in EGA, in Vakil, in Hartshorne, in stack project and in the very large amount of works, books, courses based on these, so maybe I should have stick with "in general". Moreover, I have seen in many places $Z$ irreducible iff $I(Z)$ is prime, even on books where they assume the empty set to be irreducible, meaning something is wrong.

Comment: @elmer Now I recommend again that we delete this useless conversation, specially your ridiculously aggressive comment.

Comment: @Roland What is ridiculously aggressive? You are the one getting aggressive, because you pretended to know what "in general" is assumed without really knowing, and then find reality uncomfortable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ has two or more points (Say $p \neq q$ are both in $X$) and is Hausdorff, then it there are open sets $U,V$ of $x$ with $p \in U$, $q \in V$ and $ U \cap V = \emptyset$.

But then $X = (X\setminus U) \cup (X \setminus V)$ (follows from $U \cap V = \emptyset$) and both are proper closed subsets of $X$ ($p$ and $q$ are in the respective complements). So $X$ is not irreducible.

So for Hausdorff spaces we have $|X| \ge 2 \Rightarrow$ $X$ is not irreducible.
Or equivalently: $X$ irreducible $\Rightarrow |X| \le 1$.

So the only non-empty Hausdorff irreducible space is a singleton (in its unique topology).

Comment: Thank you that is correct. Irreducible Hausdorff spaces is trivial, since Zariski topology is more important in this area.