# Noetherian Hausdorff Topological Spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

What are the Noetherian Hausdorff topological spaces? (We know that Zariski topology is not Hausdorff, so we should look for another topological spaces).

I would be thankful for any comments.

Comment: In some cases the Zariski topology yields a Hausdorff space, though.

Comment: A noetherian space decomposes as a finite union of irreducible components. Now use your previous question.

Comment: @Roland so it is same as before?

Comment: No, the result is a finite discrete space...

Comment: @ That is true. Each element is the irreducible component.Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rolands idea: A Noetherian space $X$ can be (uniquely) written as $$X = \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$$ where each $C_i$ is an irreducible component of $X$ and $N$ is some finite number.

So each $C_i$ is a Hausdorff irreducible space and we saw [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2804377/4280) that this means that $|C_i| = 1$ and so $|X|  = N$. So $X$ is finite and discrete (a finite Hausdorff space is discrete as all singletons are closed, so all subsets are closed so all subsets are open).

Another proof can go by contradiction: if $X$ is an infinite Hausdorff space then $X$ has an infinite discrete subspace $D$, and if $X$ were Noetherian, so would its subspace $D$ be and this is clearly false.

Answer (score 11):

Every subspace of a Noetherian space is Noetherian and hence compact. In a Hausdorff space, all compact subspaces are closed. Thus every subspace is closed and hence the topology is discrete. By compactness, the space is also finite.

Answer (score 2):

You might know that in Noetherian space $X$ every subset is compact. So if $a \in X$ then $X-\{a\}$ is compact. For every $y \in X-\{a\}$ choose $y\in U_y$ and $a \in V_y$ open subsets of $X$ such that $U_y \cap V_y = \emptyset$ by Hausdorffness. By compactness of $X-\{a\}$ finite $U_{y_i}$s cover $X-\{a\}$. Consider $\cap V_{y_i} $- this is a open set such that $a \in \cap V_{y_i}$ and $\cap V_{y_i} \bigcap (X-\{a\})= \emptyset$. So $\{a\}$ is a open set. The result then follows from compactness of $X$.